# Determine a the length of an operation's result in any base

Tags: number-theory, project-euler

In Project Euler [problem 16](http://projecteuler.net/problem=16), you have to sum up the digits of $2^{1000}$.
 A non-brute force solution had the prerequisite to know the length of the result beforehand and the following formula gave the result: $1000\log_{10}(2)+1$.
 Could someone explain where this came from?  And add a generalization (and resources on the background of the topic).

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  Are you asking how to arrive at the given formula for the number of digits in a large power of $2$?

Comment: In general, every integer $n$ is between $10^{r-1}$ and $10^r$ for some $r$, and such an integer has $r$ digits (can you see why?). And the base-10 log of $n$ is between $r-1$ and $r$. So, the number of digits is one more than the integer part of the base-10 log. Now: generalize this to base $b$ for arbitrary (integer) $b$ (greater than 1).

Comment: @SammyBlack: more generally, how to predict the number of digits in the result of an operation. Gerry Myerson: I'll try to understand about your explanation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understand now, thanks. Though I can only empirically prove your first "lemma"...

Comment: Worth having a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410738/digits-in-a-large-power-of-two and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426138/is-there-an-algorithm-to-find-the-number-of-digits-in-2n-where-n-is-a-positive and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335055/what-is-the-relationship-between-base-and-number-of-digits and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459564/find-the-number-of-digits-of-20132013